# Redirect only one website to https

Tags: apache-2.4

I have one serveur with multiple domains.
I'd like to redirect only one "site-internet.com" to ssl configuration.

I'd like to do :

- www.site-internet.com => https://www.site-internet.com
- site-internet.com => https://www.site-internet.com
- test.site-internet.com => **http**://test.site-internet.com

This is my apache conf file

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.site-internet\.com$[NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test.site-internet.com/$1 [NC,R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.site-internet\.com$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site-internet\.com$
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

But this don't work. What should I correct ?

Comment: @LatinSuD The "NC" flag is just one flag, not two separate flags. It's all very well documented on Apache's website, so there's no need for random baseless guessing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So when you put 2 RewriteConds, they are "AND"-ed, meaning they both need to be true in order to apply the RewriteRule. You need to use [OR] to overcome this. Also, I don't get why you need the code for "not redirecting".

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site-internet\.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site-internet\.com$
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This work like a charm for www and non www to redirect to https but when I am trying to access test.site-internet.com, I am redirected to www.site-internet.com even after cleared browser cache.

Comment: That has to do with some other rules.